# Testes com rspec - problemas com stub e should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Sou novato em testes e tenho dois testes com problemas, um helper e um model, sendo:

```
1) TodosHelper TodosHelper#visibility(todo) when todo is public 
 Failure/Error: before { helper.stub :current_user => current_user }
 
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `stub' for #<#<Class:0x00000006d3c9e8>:0x00000006d723b8>
 # ./spec/helpers/todos_helper_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3)  Bookmark Bookmark user watch a todo when todo is public can creates a bookmark relationship with todo
   Failure/Error:
     lambda {
      FactoryGirl.create(:bookmark, :todo => todo)
     }.should change(user.bookmarks, :count).by(1)
     
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `should' for #<Proc:0x00000006f783b0>
 # ./spec/models/bookmark_spec.rb:21:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Estou usando as seguintes gems:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'capybara'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
  gem 'rspec-activemodel-mocks'
end
```

e testes, model:

```
describe "watch a todo" do

      context "when todo is public" do

        let(:todo) { FactoryGirl.create(:todo, :public => true) }

        it "can creates a bookmark relationship with todo" do

          lambda {
            FactoryGirl.create(:bookmark, :todo => todo)
          }.should change(user.bookmarks, :count).by(1)

          user.bookmark?(todo).should be_true
        end
      end
    end
```

helper:

```
RSpec.describe TodosHelper, type: :helper do

  describe TodosHelper do

    let(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:todo) { FactoryGirl.create(:todo) }
    before { helper.stub :current_user => current_user }
    describe "#visibility(todo)" do
      subject { helper.visibility(todo) }
      context "when todo is public" do
        before { todo.stub(:public? => true) }
        it { should eq "public" }
          end
...
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia? esse métodos estão *deprecated*?

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
helper = double
helper.stub(current_user: current_user)
```

Ou:

```
helper = double
helper.stub(:current_user).and_return(current_user)
```